# error = 13 permission denied while attempting to get adb version

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse-adt

I am completely new to linux. Recently installed eclipse with the adt bundle but when i launch it it throws the following exception:

[image]

I have tried many things mentioned on different forums like adding sdk paths to the environment variables but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of solution:
1) Check that you can get adb version by typing `adb version` in console.
1.1) Check that you are using same adb in eclipse and in console if #1 is working. Type `which adb` in console and compare path to adb with path to adb in Eclipse.
2) Open `AVD manager` and check that android tools are installed.
3) Check path
4) Check that `adb` wasn't installed by other user, or check execution rights.

Solution that helped:
install IA32 if you are using 64 bit architecture.

`

Comment: Thanks for the response. it says no command adb found. it means the path variables have not been set correctly. Could you pleas help me that ?

Comment: Try to run in console `export PATH=/home/sayedjalilhassan/opt/sdk/platform-tools/:$PATH` and then `adb version` also check that `adb` file is on his place

Comment: Thanks. I edited the ~/.bashrc file and added the paths to platform-tools and tools folders and it worked.

Comment: sorry it removed the launch time exception but when i try to launch a project the same exception is thrown again

Comment: Do you mean from `Eclipse`?

Comment: Yes i am using eclipse. It wont event let me create an emulator and sdk manager also doesnt open.

Comment: Do you running shell (when `adb version` is working) and Eclipse from same user?

Comment: Try to add to the bashrc:
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools

export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Comment: fix the patch wehere is needed

Comment: my sdk is located at /home/myfolder/opt/sdk. I added the paths accordingly but still no luck :/

Comment: Ok i changed the directory permission to 777 and now it says "no file or directory found" while getting the adb version

Comment: Thank you for your time. since i am using a 64 bit machine, some one suggested to install IA32 library. Let me see if that works

Comment: Installing the 32 bit libraries fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan I'll added it to the my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The directory of SDK has limited permission.
You have to change the permission.

**To change the permission:**

```
$sudo chmod -R 777 platform-tools
```

Comment: For me what solved the issue was `chmod -R 777 platform-tools
` with an `-R`

Comment: I have to give access to tools only instead of plateform-tools.
but thanks it helped me to figure out the problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the above, and also for emulator folder. Was able to see a permission error there in idea.log.

`$sudo chmod -R 777 emulator`